# SQL Parse String, got to be a better way

Tags: sql, sql-server, string

I have a somewhat funky string that I can't seem to find a better way to parse other than just using the numerical position and a bunch of substrings.

Is there a better approach to break this string out?

```
Declare @EXTERNAL_KEY Varchar(100) = 'ABC_2015SP_DEFG1321.088TR'

Print Substring(@EXTERNAL_KEY,CHARINDEX('_',@EXTERNAL_KEY)+8,4)+' '+Replace(Substring(@EXTERNAL_KEY,CHARINDEX('_',@EXTERNAL_KEY)+12,8),'.',' ')+' '+Substring(@EXTERNAL_KEY,CHARINDEX('_',@EXTERNAL_KEY)+20,2)
```

The End result I am hoping to achieve:

```
DEFG 1321 088 TR
```

Comment: is the format fixed?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [STUFF](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188043.aspx) + [PARSENAME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) + [REPLACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx)

```
SELECT  STUFF(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@EXTERNAL_KEY,'_','.'),2),5,0,' ') +' '+ STUFF(PARSENAME(@EXTERNAL_KEY,1),4,0,' ')
```

Output:

```
DEFG 1321 088 TR
```

Answer (score 2):

Fixed format assumed

```
Declare @EXTERNAL_KEY Varchar(100) = 'ABC_2015SP_DEFG1321.088TR';
select  stuff(stuff(replace(right(@EXTERNAL_KEY,14), '.', ' ') ,13,0,' '), 5,0,' ')
```

Answer (score 1):

If your format is fixed, Try to use `'PARSENAME'` AND `'LEFT'` and `'RIGHT'` function to avoid static indexing

```
DECLARE @Str NVARCHAR(MAX)='ABC_2015SP_DEFG1321.088TR'
SELECT   LEFT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Str,'_','.'),2),4)+' '+RIGHT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Str,'_','.'),2),4)+' '+LEFT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Str,'_','.'),1),3)+' '+RIGHT(PARSENAME(REPLACE(@Str,'_','.'),1),2)
```